# Terraform | GCP | google_container_node_pool | node_count

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

Could anyone kindly explain the `node_count` Terraform argument below (from [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#node_count))?

`node_count` - (Optional) The number of nodes per instance group. This field can be used to update the number of nodes per instance group but should not be used alongside `autoscaling`.

- What does "per instance group" mean?
- Why shouldn't `node_count` be used alongside `autoscaling`?
- Is there a way to control autoscaling triggers for the resource `google_container_node_pool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not per "instance" but per "instance group". If you're coming from AWS it's like an [auto scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html). You can read more about it in [GCP's documentation for instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups).

You're basically being given the choice between a static amount of instances in the node pool (by using the [`node_count` parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#node_count)) or to allow the node pool to automatically scale and set the min and max size of the node pool via the [`autoscaling.min_node_count`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#min_node_count) and [`autoscaling.max_node_count`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#max_node_count) parameters.

With a container node pool the point is that you are running this to provide compute for containers running on Kubernetes via [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine). In Kubernetes, the [cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) is responsible for scaling compute to support the demand from the containers that are running or pending so that is what will scale out the size of the node pool.